# validate Kafka reassignment for partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to validate the balanced of the topics , include replica and Isr

I will give some example of wrong balanced ( master01 is the zookeper server , and we defined 3 replicate )

**on that example we can see that kafka brokers are missing from some Isr**

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh  --describe --zookeeper  master01:2181 --topic mno.de.pola.trump  Topic:mno.de.pola.trump  PartitionCount:100  ReplicationFactor:3  Configs:  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 0  Leader: 1017  Replicas: 1017,1018,1016   Isr: 1017,1018,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 1  Leader: 1018  Replicas: 1018,1016,1017   Isr: 1018,1017,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 2  Leader: 1016  Replicas: 1016,1017,1018   Isr: 1016,1018  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 3  Leader: 1017  Replicas: 1017,1016,1018   Isr: 1017,1018,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 4  Leader: 1018  Replicas: 1018,1017,1016   Isr: 1018,1017,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 5  Leader: 1016  Replicas: 1016,1018,1017   Isr: 1016,1018,1017  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 6  Leader: 1017  Replicas: 1017,1018,1016   Isr: 1017,1018
```

**on the following example we can see that Leader on partitions are more on broker 1017**

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh  --describe --zookeeper  master01:2181 --topic mno.de.pola.trump  Topic:mno.de.pola.trump   PartitionCount:100  ReplicationFactor:3  Configs:  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 0  Leader: 1017  Replicas: 1017,1018,1016  Isr: 1017,1018,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 1  Leader: 1018  Replicas: 1018,1016,1017  Isr: 1018,1017,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 2  Leader: 1017  Replicas: 1016,1017,1018  Isr: 1016,1018.1017  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 3  Leader: 1017  Replicas: 1017,1016,1018  Isr: 1017,1018,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 4  Leader: 1018  Replicas: 1018,1017,1016  Isr: 1018,1017,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 5  Leader: 1016  Replicas: 1016,1018,1017  Isr: 1016,1018,1017  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 6  Leader: 1017  Replicas: 1017,1018,1016  Isr: 1017,1018,1016
```

**on the following example we can see that brokers are missing from Replica**

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh  --describe --zookeeper  master01:2181 --topic mno.de.pola.trump  Topic:mno.de.pola.trump  PartitionCount:100  ReplicationFactor:3  Configs:  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 0  Leader: 1017  Replicas: 1017,1018       Isr: 1017,1018,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 1  Leader: 1018  Replicas: 1018,1016,1017  Isr: 1018,1017,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 2  Leader: 1017  Replicas: 1016,1017,1018  Isr: 1016,1018,1017  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 3  Leader: 1017  Replicas: 1017,1016       Isr: 1017,1018,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 4  Leader: 1018  Replicas: 1018,1017,1016  Isr: 1018,1017,1016  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 5  Leader: 1016  Replicas: 1016,1018,1017  Isr: 1016,1018,1017  Topic:
mno.de.pola.trump  Partition: 6  Leader: 1017 Replicas:  1017,1018,1016  Isr: 1017,1018,1016
```

And so on

.

.

.

*so my question:
I will happy to know about some tool ( script ) that can validate the output from kafka-topics.sh --describe
any ideas about this*

**example of good balanced configuration**

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh  --describe --zookeeper  master01:2181 --topic mno.de.pola.trump

        Topic: mno.de.pola.trump      PartitionCount:100      ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:
        Topic: mno.de.pola.trump     Partition: 0    Leader: 1017    Replicas: 1017,1018,1016        Isr: 1017,1018,1016
        Topic: mno.de.pola.trump     Partition: 1    Leader: 1018    Replicas: 1018,1016,1017        Isr: 1018,1017,1016
        Topic: mno.de.pola.trump     Partition: 2    Leader: 1016    Replicas: 1016,1017,1018        Isr: 1016,1018,1017
        Topic: mno.de.pola.trump     Partition: 3    Leader: 1017    Replicas: 1017,1016,1018        Isr: 1017,1018,1016
        Topic: mno.de.pola.trump     Partition: 4    Leader: 1018    Replicas: 1018,1017,1016        Isr: 1018,1017,1016
        Topic: mno.de.pola.trump     Partition: 5    Leader: 1016    Replicas: 1016,1018,1017        Isr: 1016,1018,1017
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this "balanced". Just "healthy". You can have all your data in 2/6 partitions, then your topic is "unbalanced"

Comment: It's a bit weird, but you could make a cron that executes every 30 mins or X time, which calls the kafka-topics.sh script, with your own implementation of the TopicCommand class' describeTopic() method. For example, sending a log somewhere. (at least in kafka 1.1, don't know if changes with versions)

Comment: @cricket_007 , do you have suggestion how to validate the output ? , I am feeling that I need to make some script for this validation , since I not get any suggestion until now

Comment: Personally, we enable JMX metrics on the brokers, and send out alerts for when we get under-replicated partitions. We also collect the broker logs and see if something is unhealthy... These things are required if you want to actually productionalize Kafka